# Schedule local notifications on user selected week days in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, notifications

The use case is that there is a form where a user can say: I want to get a notification on X days (e.g Monday, Friday and Sunday) at 14:00. The application is in react native but I'm just calling a native swift function to schedule the notification:

```swift
import Foundation
import UserNotifications

@objc(Reminders)
class Reminders: NSObject {
  @objc func setReminder(
    _ message: NSString,
    daysV days: NSArray,
    hourV hour: NSInteger,
    minuteV minute: NSInteger
  ) {
    // We'll replace all scheduled notifications entirely
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()

    // Create a notification for each day that has been passed
    let daysC: [Int] = days.map { $0 as! Int }
    for day in daysC {
      var date = DateComponents()
      date.weekday = day
      date.hour = hour
      date.minute = minute

      let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
      content.title = "Reminder"
      content.body = message as String

      let userCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
      let dateTime = userCalendar.date(from: date)
      let triggerDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday,.hour,.minute], from: dateTime as! Date)
      let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDate, repeats: true)
      let identifier = "TMWTE\(day)"
      let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
      let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
      center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: { (error) in
        if let error = error {
          print(error);
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is get each of the weekday included in a list sent from JS and schedule a notification for it. So if the user selects Monday and Wednesday the array will be `[1,3]` and I'll schedule a notification for each day respectively.

What's actually happening however is that I get X notifications at once in the first day. Thus if the user selects all days then in the next `triggerDate` I'll get 7 notifications.

Being a complete novice in Swift I may be doing something irrational, but I cannot figure it out at the moment. Now I've also tried to set the `date.day` to be the next Saturday, Sunday etc.. but that causes no notifications to be shown, which makes me think that I'm missing something basic here.

Thanks!